# Close custom dialog another method

Tags: android

Method to create dialog:

```
 public void reservar(View view) {

            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_reserva);
            d.show();
}
```

Here, i am create another method i cant close the 'd' dialog:

```
public void reservarD(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar reserva", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){


            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
```

Comment: I am trying to make sense of what you're trying to achieve here. And, it's really confusing. I think what you are doing here is. You created a method to Show a dialog and another to close it?

Comment: Hello, I don't understand what you want to do but if you want to close your dialog from outside of your method then you have to require to define your dialog object globally.

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko, sorry! i am a newbie im Java(i`m a front-end dev, rsrsrs).  I'm venturing into this language in this month but the Answer solved my problem, i did declared in the scope the method... i should in the global :S newbie problem rsrsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define dialog d as a global variable.

```
Dialog d;

public void reservar(View view) {
                d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_reserva);
                d.show();
    }
```

then

```
public void anotherMethod(){
   if(d!=null){
        d.dismiss();
    }
}
```